# Why would increasing layers in PyTorch Transformer significantly increase loss?

Tags: transformer, pytorch, hyperparameter-optimization, machine-translation

I have a simple `torch.nn.Transformer` module for machine translation on the [Multi30k dataset](https://github.com/multi30k/dataset). It performs pretty well (32.2 Bleu score) but I looked at scaling up model size. Running in a sweep in Weights & Biases I notice that increasing layers has an inverse relationship to performance, it really drops off adding more layers to encoder/decoder.

Why would this happen, could there be something I'm missing (vanishing gradients, different input shapes, learning rate needs to be adjusted?). I had the assumption that a larger model would give at least equal performance if not better.

[image: comparison of num decoder and encoder layers and val loss]

I used [the code here](https://github.com/aladdinpersson/Machine-Learning-Collection/blob/master/ML/Pytorch/more_advanced/seq2seq_transformer/seq2seq_transformer.py) as a starting point and converted to Pytorch Lightning.

Comment: There are many reasons for this: (1) overfitting, (2) complex models require longer training time and more data, and (3) issues related to optimization.